# Applying a function to a multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I have defined a function that replaces the variables within an array, with that previously generated by a LabelEncoder. I have it working for a 1D array, though I now want to make it work for a multi dimensional array with a for loop. But the for loop doesn't seem to iterate over the rows in the way I had expected. I think it is a simple mistake, but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

This is my current code:

```
def new_data (i):
    for x in i:
        x[0] = np.where(x[0] =='40-49', 2, x[0])
        x[0] = np.where(x[0] == '50-59', 3, x[0])
       #Etc for each item
        prediction = classifier.predict([[x]])
        prediction1 = np.where(prediction > 0.6, 1, prediction)
        prediction1 = np.where(prediction <= 0.6, 0, prediction)
        if prediction1 == 0:
            return 'Prediction: No recurrence-events, with a confidence of: ' + str(prediction)
        else:
            return 'Prediction: Recurrence-events, with a confidence of: ' + str(prediction)
```

The input would then be:

```
new_predict = np.array(['40-49', 'ge40', '25-29', '6-8'], 
                       ['40-49', 'ge40', '25-29', '6-8'], 
                       ['40-49', 'ge40', '25-29', '6-8'])
new_data(new_predict)
```

Then I would hope to have an output such as:

```
Prediction: No recurrence-events, with a confidence of: [prediction]
Prediction: No recurrence-events, with a confidence of: [prediction]
Prediction: No recurrence-events, with a confidence of: [prediction]
```

Where each prediction is related to a row within the array.

But I am currently only getting a type error, rather than it iterating over the components of the array.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tom/MSc Project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-19-fcc97a6a2285>", line 1, in <module>
    new_predict = np.array(['40-49', 'ge40', '25-29', '6-8', 'yes', 2, 'right', 'right_up', 'no'],['40-49', 'ge40', '25-29', '6-8', 'yes', 2, 'right', 'right_up', 'no']
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Comment: Does numpy has something like the pandas apply?

Comment: Showing the full list of where's does not add anything to the question.  A proper question would show `prediction` (preferably a small sample), the result of the code, AND what you expect.  This question is incomplete.

Comment: @hpaulj, you were very correct, my apologies, I am still learning. I have adjusted hopefully reflected what you suggested. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Check the inputs to `np.array`.The 2nd should be a valid dtype, not a data list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```py
new_predict = np.array(['40-49', 'ge40', '25-29', '6-8'], 
                       ['40-49', 'ge40', '25-29', '6-8'], 
                       ['40-49', 'ge40', '25-29', '6-8'])
```

You want this instead:

```py
new_predict = np.array([['40-49', 'ge40', '25-29', '6-8'], 
                       ['40-49', 'ge40', '25-29', '6-8'], 
                       ['40-49', 'ge40', '25-29', '6-8']])
...
```

Not sure what's happening below, why are you wrapping x in double square brackets?
Also, why are you setting something to `prediction1` and immediately overwrite it in the the line that follows?

```py
...
prediction = classifier.predict([[x]])
prediction1 = np.where(prediction > 0.6, 1, prediction)
prediction1 = np.where(prediction <= 0.6, 0, prediction)
...
```